# quarkus-resteasy-mutiny extension was not present warning when I use quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson

Tags: java, quarkus

I got the message when resteasy-reactive project.

(build-70) [io.quarkus.resteasy.common.deployment.ResteasyCommonProcessor] null: Quarkus detected the need for Mutiny reactive programming support, however the quarkus-resteasy-mutiny extension was not present.
I used quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson with below dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In my understanding if I added resteasy-reactive-jackson, then it includes automatically .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.smallrye.reactive</groupId>
    <artifactId>mutiny</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So, I don't need add "quarkus-resteasy-mutiny" extension, although I use Uni/Multi.

Could you please let me know to remove this "WARN", when I see RestEasyCommonProcessor" code, it is checked RESTEASY_MUTINY for capability, but seems like need to check other way which can be used for smallrye reactive
PS I used "quarkus-keycloak-admin-client" for other purpose, seems because of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have both the RESTEasy Classic and the RESTEasy Reactive extensions.

The message is coming from the RESTEasy Classic extension.

You should only have one of them or you will have all sorts of weird behaviors.

Comment: I used only resteasy reactive.